# Forward multiple emails?

Tags: applescript, mail.app, automator

I am using an online email parser.  This selects specific text from an email and transfers it to an Excel spreadsheet which I shall use in CRM.

I use Apple Mail and have 7000 emails in an account that I need to send to the parser.  I can do this manually, one-by-one successfully.  I now need to automate this process so it can run overnight.  If I use an Apple Mail rule (forward or redirect) the content of the email is not forwarded in its original form which trips up the parser because it works to a predefined template (it needs to see the same info in the same place each time).

I'm guessing that the best way to do this then might be to write an Applescript to replicate the manual process but to do it repetitively until the job is done.  Can anyone help me write the script?  Or perhaps let me know if there's a simpler/better way altogether to do this.

With kindest regards.  Andrew

Comment: A redirect shouldn’t change the Mail content, what exactly is confusing the parser in that case? Also: what have you tried so far to get a script working?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the parser would need an email forwarded to it in order to work.

If it can work with .emlx files, you can get them from `~/Library/Mail/V6/<key>/All Mail.inbox/*`. Just ensure that all attachments and remote images are loaded. Also, copying all of them to "On my Mac" folder will ensure that everything is local, even if the real account is IMAP.

Alternatively, if the parser works with plain text/ RTF files, you can save an email at a time with File > Save as > RTF/ Plain text/ Raw source.